# how to redirect non www url become www. into htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

i just want to setting file .htaccess for redirect non www url to www. but the case is not common.

if the url like this `https://<domain name>.com`  become `https://www.<domain name>.com`

i already set the code like this. but didn't work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

that code is working if we type just `<domain name>.com`  in browser. but when someone type manualy on browser like this `https://<domain name>.com` i mean type manualy the `https://`   can it turn into `https://www.<domain name>.com`

so for this .htaccess i want to do result like this

if type

`<domainName>.com` it become `https://www.<domainName>.com`

`www.<domainName>.com` it become `https://www.<domainName>.com`

`https://<domainName>.com` it become `https://www.<domainName>.com`

`http://<domainName>.com` it become `https://www.<domainName>.com`

please help.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: yes it works, but when i type only <domain>.com without https://  . it can't add www. in the front

Comment: That's not correct. This rule does redirect `http://example.com` as well due to first condition with `OR`. Make sure this is topmost rule and you test after completely clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# uniform host name
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com$0 [R=301,L]
```

It includes a deep link forwarding.

Comment: thank you for reply. but sorry, it still not rewrite the url

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```